# Identity Server and Accessing state values in MVC Controller?

Tags: owin, identityserver4

I am setting a custom state paramter value in **OnRedirectToIdentityProvider** and able to access it in **OnMessageReceived**. This custom state value can be accessed in MVC Controller but the value is in an **encrypted** format. How can I access this in a **decrypted** manner in Controller. Below is  my code:

```
private static Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {

        var stateQueryString = notification.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=');
        var protectedState = stateQueryString[1];
        var state = notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
        state.Dictionary.Add("stateUTName", "chandigarh");

        notification.ProtocolMessage.State = stateQueryString[0] + "=" + notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(state);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
private Task OnMessageReceived(MessageReceivedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        string mycustomparameter;
        var protectedState = notification.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=')[1];
        var state = notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
        state.Dictionary.TryGetValue("stateUTName", out mycustomparameter);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

The Value obtained in Controller looks like: `OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=CfijlEY2jd9Jv4J7i5qy0K1ZZ5x2FR5ZraXo2dDVWl-a2RppU46kHpnoZe2mLJ2qpXFlpMRnu1nxKPYXepR4KwnhxAll88xSZmK41BsfIVkmCa34dfHK_RdBwRZW3cwHqIsD1N4Cqmr655xjK-gSr53zetwZeUq0UX-nBTpz1TZTgc64-8JOLiXPEVlvLM6KYZNQYGBkoCNCNCV_GEbgx0U1QuGPuHxglJD3SGbKF9bo_OjhI6L-U-hPbalY0Fa-`